# Trying to display message for few seconds but nothing display

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display message for few seconds but nothing displays, what is problem in my code?

```
    var my_css_class = { border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' };

    var div = "<div>" + Message + "<\div>";

    $(div).css(my_css_class);

    alert(div);
    $(div).show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your div isn't added to your page, this is why it won't show.

Try

```
$(div).prependTo('body').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
```

To clean up your DOM afterwards, you could:

```
$(div).prependTo('body').show().delay(2000).fadeOut(400, function () {
    $(div).remove();
});
```

Comment: I removed the .remove() which apparently doesn't queue in after the delay. Now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/QRGHM/2/

Answer (score 0):

First append your div to body

```
var div = "<div id='yourDiv'>" + Message + "<\div>";

$(body).append(div)`
```

Give your div an id and then you can use `setTimeOut` method

```
setTimeout('$("#yourDiv").hide()', 2000); //hides the message after 2 sec.
```